# The Bottom Navigation covers my Drawer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write an application for Android with a drawer and a bottom navigation. As there is still no official library I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar).

Now I have a bottom navigation, but it covers the drawer when I use it. Roughike, the creator of the tutorial, try to give a solution to the problem, and I quote:

> "All you need to do is instead of attaching the BottomBar to your
>   Activity, attach it to the view That has your content".

But by doing so, I can no longer see the fragment that should be visible in my activity.

How can I fix this bug?

I try to give you a bit of code to give you an idea.

```
private BottomBar mBottomBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setDrawerCurrent(R.id.nav_cerca);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    FragmentCerca fragment = new FragmentCerca();
    fragmentTransaction.add(getViewContentId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    mBottomBar = BottomBar.attach(getViewContent(), savedInstanceState);
    mBottomBar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottombar_menu, new OnMenuTabClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomBarItemOne) {
                // The user selected item number one.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {
            if (menuItemId == R.id.bottomBarItemOne) {
                // The user reselected item number one, scroll your content to top.
            }
        }
    });


    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
    mBottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // Necessary to restore the BottomBar's state, otherwise we would
    // lose the current tab on orientation change.
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Note: `getViewContent()` is a method of a parent class that manages the views and passes the current one.

Comment: `attach`'s doc says: "Bind the BottomBar to the specified View's parent" it looks like you need to attach it to `Fragment.getView()` or similar. Check the source of that method.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I tried to do as you say, but in this way the app crashes...

Comment: Did you try attaching the bottom bar to `Fragment.getView()` in `onActivityCreated()` ?